# Trigger will not execute stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

I have the following trigger:

```
USE SomeDB
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [Staging].[RunPivot15] 
ON [Staging].[UriData]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    EXEC [Staging].[PivotData]
END
```

It will not fire. The table concerned receives about 30 rows every five minutes. From that point I am stuck. I have been reading that because more than one row is being inserted I have to run a cursor. I have tried the cursor and cannot get that to work either.

Can you advise what the best approach here is?

TIA

Comment: Have you tried running this while watching with the SQL Profiler on a test environment? That may tell you a bit more about what is (or isn't) happening.

Comment: It's a hosted server that I don't have access to the profiler. The hosting company said they don't allow bulk inserts. I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Considering that you aren't referencing`inserted`, nor passing any parameters to your stored procedure, I can't see why you would need a cursor. (Plus you've heard wrong, you dont need to use a cursor to handle multiple rows in an insert/update/etc just treat the data like everything else is on your database, a dataset). Most likely the SP is bring fired but it isn't doing what you think it is. Without knowing the definition of the SP though, impossible to tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's highly unlikely the trigger to not run. Add a couple of print statements around the procedure call in your trigger, eventually in your stored procedure too. This will help you to trace the execution when you run an update statement in Management Studio to fire the trigger.

```
USE SomeDB
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO    

ALTER TRIGGER [Staging].[RunPivot15] 
ON [Staging].[UriData]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    PRINT 'Before call.'
    EXEC [Staging].[PivotData]
    PRINT 'After call.'
END
```

Then run an update statement in Management Studio and check Messages tab to see is your messages printed.

```
update Staging.RunPivot15 set SomeColumn = SomeColumn where SomeColumn = SomeValue
```

No, you do not need cursors. When your trigger is executed, if more than one row is affected, there will be multiple rows in inserted / deleted pseudo tables too. In your case you do not read which rows are updated either, so just run the procedure. If you need to know which rows exactly are modified, then write code to process them in set-based approach (all rows at once). Looping with cursors is practically never good idea in the database.

Comment: I tried the print statements and that led me to find there was a schema that was not visible previously. When I added this [SomeSchema.][Staging].[PivotData] it worked. Thank you for your help, I learned how to debug a trigger. I just need to wait and see if it does it automatically.

Comment: *Looping with cursors is practically never good idea in the database* - and even **more so** inside a **trigger** - which should be very small, fast and nimble - that doesn't go well with "cursor" .....

Comment: If I do it manually as suggested above, it works fine. But it doesn't work automatically.

Comment: By work fine, I mean it fires the SPROC which has been tested independently.

Comment: With normal inserts the trigger will fire (unless disabled), which you tried in SSMS and proved it works. So in this case your inserts looks like are not normal insert. Are these rows inserted using [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for example? In this case by default triggers will not fire, unless FIRE_TRIGGERS option is specified.